# Android - Swipe/Fling + MapView with MapOverlay

Tags: android, google-maps, position, android-mapview, swipe

I have an android app with an activity that swipes (left to right) between 3 views. One of those views displays GoogleMaps. In addition to that I need to have scrolling up and down (not in the map but in the other 2 views) to display all the content. I had some problem to make the app understand the gesture of swiping and not the scrolling when needed but I found a great solution here:
http://www.jmstudio.org/archives/391

My problem now is that in my MapView I want to show the position of the user. So I implemented a MapOverlay class like this:

protected class MyLocationOverlay extends com.google.android.maps.Overlay {

```
        @Override
        public boolean draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView, boolean shadow, long when) {
            Paint paint = new Paint();

            super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);
            // Converts lat/lng-Point to OUR coordinates on the screen.
            Point myScreenCoords = new Point();

            mapView.getProjection().toPixels(p, myScreenCoords);

            paint.setStrokeWidth(1);
            paint.setARGB(255, 255, 255, 255);
            paint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);

            Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(), R.drawable.positiondot);

            canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, myScreenCoords.x, myScreenCoords.y, paint);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

And then from my activity I call

```
                     List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
                     MyLocationOverlay mapOverlay;
                     mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
                     mapOverlay = new MyLocationOverlay();
                     mapOverlays.add(mapOverlay);
```

This works, but once the position is shown the swiping is not recognized. And if the user removes the dot (pressing a button mapOverlays.removeAll(mapOverlays); is called) then the swiping works again, but of course the position is not shown anymore. It is like the list disables the swiping for some reason.

So I want to have both the position shown and the swiping working at the same time. My code for the swiping is more or less the one in the link I provided (just implemented my views in the xml). What is wrong and how to fix?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: did you ever find a way to fix this? I have the exact same situation.

Comment: no sorry.. If you find something please send it here too!

Comment: will do. so far I no leads though after ~4 hours of playing around. my only idea is to add buttons to control my mapview, but that's a second-rate solution.

Comment: this is what I did.. But it is not a first-rate solution for me either